# Eighth grade problem involving some physics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on this problem that someone gave me.
Two cyclists head off simultaneously from two towns situated at a distance of $240$ km length.

Knowing that one covered the same distance in 3 hours(lets denote as the first one) as the other did in 5 hours and the time until they met is 6 hours. Find how much time would it take to the second cyclist to get at the half part of the road (after 6 hours passed of course).

I would really like to find a solution, but I am pretty bad as such types of problems. Denoting velocity=v time=t and d= distance. Here is my try: First I try to find the velocity of each cyclist. $$v=\frac{d}{t}=40\frac{km}{h}$$ 
This velocity is equal to the average velocity of the cyclists $v=\frac{v_A+v_B}{2}$ Also knowing that $v_A=\frac{5}{3}v_B$ I get that  $v=\frac{8}{6}v_B$ which gives the velocity of the driver B is $30\frac{km}{h}$  yielding to $v_A=50\frac{km}{h}$ So the distance done by B is $30\cdot 6=180$km But that is already after half of the road... I would appreciate to get some help in order to get on the half part of the road.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $3x$ km is the distance the first one travels in $3$ hours or the distance the second one travels in $5$ hours.

$\Rightarrow$ $x$ km/h is the velocity of the first cyclist and $0.6x$ km/h is the velocity of the second cyclist.

They need to cycle for $6$ hours in total before they met, which means they take $6$ hours together to cover the entire distance $240$ km, which means each hour, the total distance covered by both cyclists is $40$ km

$\Rightarrow x+0.6x=40$, is this enough?

Comment: wait, how did you find the velocity to be $0.6$ km/h? I got a bit higher...

Comment: No, it's not $0.6$km/h, it's $0.6x$ km/h, in terms of $x$.

Comment: Just in case you need the solution, $x=25$.

Comment: Thanks! This give the velocity to be 15. But I have 30, can you tell me where I went wrong ?

Comment: They are cycling in opposite directions, so when they meet together (after $6$ hours) they will have covered $240$ km in total, so each hour they cover $40$ km in total (not on average).

Comment: You said "This velocity is equal to the average velocity of the cyclists", it's actually the sum, not the mean (average).

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$d_1$ the distance covered for cyclist 1
$d_2$ the distance covered for cyclist 2

we have

$$
6 v_1 = d_1 \\
6 v_2 = d_2 \\
240  = d_1 + d_2 \\
v_1 =\frac{5}{3} v_2
$$

Solving this linear system we obtain

$v_1 = 25, v_2 = 15, d_1 = 150, d_2 = 90$ etc.